# gapi batchGet with two metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I call the Analytics Reporting API V4 batchGet method with this code:

```
gapi.client.analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet( {
                  "reportRequests":[
                  {
                    "viewId":VIEW_ID,
                    "dateRanges":[
                      {
                        "startDate":"7daysAgo",
                        "endDate":"today"
                      }],
                    "metrics":[
                      {
                          "expression":"ga:pageviews" //correct answer
                        //"expression":"ga:pageviews,ga:users" //error!!
                      }],
                    "dimensions":[
                        {
                            "name":"ga:pageTitle"
                        }],
                    "orderBys":[
                        {
                            "fieldName": "ga:pageviews",
                            "sortOrder": "DESCENDING"
                        }]
                  }]
                } ).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.result)

                })
                .then(null, function(err) {
                    // Log any errors.
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

When using a single metric, the result is correct, but I need to query the API with two metrics and this is when the error happens.
This message is logged in console:

```
message": "Invalid value 'ga:pageviews,ga:users' for metric parameter.
```

What is the correct way to do the query with two or more metrics?
In the query explorer https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ this kind of query are possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try to read the documentation of the api, which clearly shows you have to use it like this:

```
 "metrics":[
             { "expression":"ga:pageviews" },
             { "expression":"ga:users" }
           ],
```